# What is the mechanism responsible for long-lasting detectable antibody titers?

Tags: immunology, immune-system, antibody, immunity, immunoglobin

As I understand, when naive B cell encounters antigen matching its receptors and is activated by a T helper cell, it can either differentiate into 4 plasma cells, produce a lot of antibodies and commit apoptosis, or into 2 memory cells waiting to be activated the next time they encounter the antigen.

On the other hand, IgG can be detected for a long time after infection.  As antibodies decay, there must be long-term production of IgGs to keep their level constant.  What is the mechanism behind that if there is no following infections?

Comment: Great question. Maybe the answer is simply that these assays are sensitive enough to detect basal levels of IgGs that memory cells continue to produce in the absence of an infection.

Comment: @DouglasMyers-Turnbull If not activated memory cells can secret antibodies, that actually answers my question.